# ACE TAO error on Configuration.cpp ACE_TEXT_RegOpenKeyEx was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, ace

I am building Adaptive Communication Environment (ACE) 6.5.8 using MinGW following steps in http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html#mingw. I use Windows10 64 bit Operating system. I am very new to building C++ projects.

I installed MinGW from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/. I believe it is a 32 bit version. I used MinGW installation Manager to download all packages.

I downloaded ACE 6.5.8 from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu/ and extracted to C:\ACE_wrappers

created config.h file inside C:\ACE_wrappers\ace

```
#define ACE_HAS_WINNT4 1
#define ACE_HAS_STANDARD_CPP_LIBRARY 1
#define ETIME 1
#define ACE_HAS_POSIX_TIME 1
#define ACE_LACKS_TIMESPEC_T 1
#include "ace/config-win32.h"
```

following the steps given, in msys shell,
`cd $ACE_ROOT/ace` and 
`make`

I got error of

````
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace'

GNUmakefile: /c/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/GNUmakefile.ACE MAKEFLAGS=w

g++ -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O3 -g -mthreads -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -DACE_HAS_CUSTOM_EXPORT_MACROS=0 -Wno-unknown-pragmas   -IC:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers -DACE_NO_INLINE -I.. -DACE_BUILD_DLL  -c  -o .shobj/Configuration.o /c/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp
In file included from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/config.h:1:0,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/config-macros.h:22,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/config-lite.h:22,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Basic_Types.h:40,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/SStringfwd.h:20,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.h:31,
                 from c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:1:
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.cpp: In constructor 'ACE_Allocator_Adapter<MALLOC>::ACE_Allocator_Adapter(const wchar_t*)':
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/ace_wchar.h:104:67: error: there are no arguments to 'ACE_Wide_To_Ascii' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'ACE_Wide_To_Ascii' must be available [-fpermissive]
 # define ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR(STRING) ACE_Wide_To_Ascii (STRING).char_rep ()
                                                                   ^
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.cpp:327:17: note: in expansion of macro 'ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR'
   : allocator_ (ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR (pool_name))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/ace_wchar.h:104:67: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
 # define ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR(STRING) ACE_Wide_To_Ascii (STRING).char_rep ()
                                                                   ^
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.cpp:327:17: note: in expansion of macro 'ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR'
   : allocator_ (ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR (pool_name))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.cpp: In constructor 'ACE_Allocator_Adapter<MALLOC>::ACE_Allocator_Adapter(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, ACE_Allocator_Adapter<MALLOC>::MEMORY_POOL_OPTIONS)':
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/ace_wchar.h:104:67: error: there are no arguments to 'ACE_Wide_To_Ascii' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'ACE_Wide_To_Ascii' must be available [-fpermissive]
 # define ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR(STRING) ACE_Wide_To_Ascii (STRING).char_rep ()
                                                                   ^
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.cpp:337:19: note: in expansion of macro 'ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR'
     : allocator_ (ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR (pool_name),
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/ace_wchar.h:104:67: error: there are no arguments to 'ACE_Wide_To_Ascii' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'ACE_Wide_To_Ascii' must be available [-fpermissive]
 # define ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR(STRING) ACE_Wide_To_Ascii (STRING).char_rep ()
                                                                   ^
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.cpp:338:19: note: in expansion of macro 'ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR'
                   ACE_TEXT_WCHAR_TO_TCHAR (lock_name),
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:9:0:
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_unistd.h: At global scope:
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_unistd.h:322:45: warning: 'useconds_t' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      useconds_t interval = 0);
                                             ^
In file included from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/sys/os_types.h:28:0,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_unistd.h:25,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_limits.h:25,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Basic_Types.h:52,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/SStringfwd.h:20,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.h:31,
                 from c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\sys\types.h:221:23: note: declared here
 typedef unsigned long useconds_t __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:9:0:
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_unistd.h:322:45: warning: 'useconds_t' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      useconds_t interval = 0);
                                             ^
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_unistd.h:322:45: warning: 'useconds_t' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_unistd.h:326:78: warning: 'useconds_t' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                      const ACE_Time_Value &tv_interval = ACE_Time_Value::zero);
                                                                              ^
In file included from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/sys/os_types.h:28:0,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_unistd.h:25,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_limits.h:25,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Basic_Types.h:52,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/SStringfwd.h:20,
                 from C:\Moto_Program\ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.h:31,
                 from c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\sys\types.h:221:23: note: declared here
 typedef unsigned long useconds_t __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::open_section(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, bool, ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:495:51: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegOpenKeyEx' was not declared in this scope
                                        &result_key)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                   ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:495:57: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                        &result_key)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:512:46: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegCreateKeyEx' was not declared in this scope
                                              )) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                              ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::remove_section(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, bool)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:561:38: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegEnumKeyEx' was not declared in this scope
                                     0) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                      ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:561:43: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                     0) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:568:66: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegDeleteKey' was not declared in this scope
   int const errnum = ACE_TEXT_RegDeleteKey (base_key, sub_section);
                                                                  ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:569:17: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
   if (errnum != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::enumerate_values(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, int, ACE_TString&, ACE_Configuration::VALUETYPE&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:599:36: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegEnumValue' was not declared in this scope
                                   0);
                                    ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:600:13: error: 'ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS' was not declared in this scope
   if (rc == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:602:18: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
   else if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::enumerate_sections(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, int, ACE_TString&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:646:36: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegEnumKeyEx' was not declared in this scope
                                   0);
                                    ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:647:13: error: 'ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS' was not declared in this scope
   if (rc == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:649:18: error: 'ERROR_MORE_DATA' was not declared in this scope
   else if (rc != ERROR_MORE_DATA && rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:649:43: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
   else if (rc != ERROR_MORE_DATA && rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::set_string_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, const ACE_TString&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:681:44: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegSetValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                         len))
                                            ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:682:10: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
       != ERROR_SUCCESS)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::set_integer_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, u_int)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:710:55: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegSetValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                         sizeof (value))) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                       ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:710:61: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                         sizeof (value))) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::set_binary_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, const void*, size_t)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:739:68: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegSetValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                         static_cast<DWORD> (length)))
                                                                    ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:740:10: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
       != ERROR_SUCCESS)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::get_string_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, ACE_TString&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:771:57: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegQueryValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                         ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:771:63: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:779:15: error: 'ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE' was not declared in this scope
       errno = ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:795:57: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegQueryValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                         ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:795:63: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::get_integer_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, u_int&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:826:50: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegQueryValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                           &length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                  ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:826:56: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                           &length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:834:15: error: 'ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE' was not declared in this scope
       errno = ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::get_binary_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, void*&, size_t&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:865:57: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegQueryValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                         ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:865:63: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:873:15: error: 'ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE' was not declared in this scope
       errno = ERROR_INVALID_DATATYPE;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:888:57: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegQueryValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                         ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:888:63: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                           &buffer_length)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::find_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, ACE_Configuration::VALUETYPE&)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:920:54: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegQueryValueEx' was not declared in this scope
                                        &buffer_length);
                                                      ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:921:17: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
   if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In member function 'virtual int ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::remove_value(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:958:58: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegDeleteValue' was not declared in this scope
   if ((errnum = ACE_TEXT_RegDeleteValue (base_key, t_name)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                          ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:958:64: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
   if ((errnum = ACE_TEXT_RegDeleteValue (base_key, t_name)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp: In static member function 'static HKEY__* ACE_Configuration_Win32Registry::resolve_key(HKEY, const ACE_TCHAR*, bool, u_long)':
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:992:51: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
   if ((errnum = RegOpenKey (hKey, 0, &result)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:1026:49: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegOpenKey' was not declared in this scope
                                          &subkey)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                 ^
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:1026:55: error: 'ERROR_SUCCESS' was not declared in this scope
                                          &subkey)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace/Configuration.cpp:1039:61: error: 'ACE_TEXT_RegCreateKeyEx' was not declared in this scope
                                                             )) !=ERROR_SUCCESS)
                                                             ^
make[1]: *** [.shobj/Configuration.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Moto_Program/ACE_wrappers/ace'
make: *** [ACE] Error 2```
````

Comment: Why do you added all those lines to ace/config.h? Did you create platform_macros.GNU? Which gcc version is this? Just pasting the errors doesn't help, how was the compiler invoked?

Comment: yes, I did create platform_macros.GNU. All those line was added to ace/config.h to solve previous error that I got building the ACE. Currently found new error and could not figure it out. I'm using gcc version 6.3.0. Sorry for pasting the error, this is my first time asking question over here.

Comment: It looks the mingw32 port is broken and needs some improvements, have you tried http://mingw-w64.org?

Comment: installed mingw-w64, same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

We compile daily with MinGW-64 without problems, see https://buildlogs.remedy.nl/win_mingw64_64_tao for the logs of our daily build. Check the config page of the build, please compare our settings with yours.